# Scala future chaining and Left/Right

Tags: scala, playframework, silhouette

I have this piece of code in the PLAY framework

```
  def ws: WebSocket = WebSocket.acceptOrResult[JsValue, JsValue] { rh =>
    implicit val req = Request(rh, AnyContentAsEmpty)

    silhouette.SecuredRequestHandler { securedRequest =>
      Future.successful(HandlerResult(Ok, Some(securedRequest.identity)))
    }.map {
      case HandlerResult(_, Some(_)) => wsFutureFlow(rh).map { flow => Right(flow) }
      case HandlerResult(r, None) => Left(r)
    }

    //    wsFutureFlow(rh).map { flow =>
    //      Right(flow)
    //    }.recover {
    //      case e: Exception =>
    //        logger.error("Cannot create websocket", e)
    //        val jsError = Json.obj("error" -> "Cannot create websocket")
    //        val result = InternalServerError(jsError)
    //        Left(result)
    //    }
  }



private def wsFutureFlow(request: RequestHeader): Future[Flow[JsValue, JsValue, NotUsed]] = {
    // Use guice assisted injection to instantiate and configure the child actor.
    implicit val timeout = Timeout(1.second) // the first run in dev can take a while :-(
    val future: Future[Any] = userParentActor ? UserParentActor.Create(request.id.toString)
    val futureFlow: Future[Flow[JsValue, JsValue, NotUsed]] = future.mapTo[Flow[JsValue, JsValue, NotUsed]]
    futureFlow
  }
```

I'm a beginner to scala and essentially what I am trying to do is authenticate the request to the `ws` endpoint. If it's authenticated, then I give it a `Flow[JsValue, JsValue, None]` to act as the WebSocket connection otherwise I need to return a `Result`. The issue I am having is I can't quite figure out how to design the futures correctly. For context, here is the authenticated endpoint example in the documentation https://www.silhouette.rocks/docs/endpoints.

The line that doesn't compile is the below:

```
  case HandlerResult(_, Some(_)) => wsFutureFlow(rh).map { flow => Right(flow) }
```

The function I'm passing to `WebSocket.acceptOrResult[JsValue, JsValue]` needs to return a `Future[Either[Result, Flow[In, Out, _]]]`. As you can see in the line that doesn't compile I'm trying to `Right()` the `Flow`, but it's not quite right. The commented section does compile though. Here is the compile error

```
[error] /home/julian/IdeaProjects/crypto-bloomberg-app/app-admin/src/main/scala/admin/controllers/HomeController.scala:32:62: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[scala.util.Right[Nothing,akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow[play.api.libs.json.JsValue,play.api.libs.json.JsValue,akka.NotUsed]]]
[error]  required: Either[play.api.mvc.Result,akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow[play.api.libs.json.JsValue, play.api.libs.json.JsValue, _]]
[error]       case HandlerResult(_, Some(_)) => wsFutureFlow(rh).map { flow => Right(flow) }
[error]                                                              ^
[error] one error found
[error] (app-admin/compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed 21-Mar-2018 4:29:04 PM
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `flatMap` instead of `map`:

```
def ws: WebSocket = WebSocket.acceptOrResult[JsValue, JsValue] { rh =>
  implicit val req = Request(rh, AnyContentAsEmpty)

  silhouette.SecuredRequestHandler { securedRequest =>
    Future.successful(HandlerResult(Ok, Some(securedRequest.identity)))
  } flatMap {
    case HandlerResult(_, Some(_)) => wsFutureFlow(rh).map(Right(_))
    case HandlerResult(r, None) => Future.successful(Left(r))
  }
}
```